# WPF combobox

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

Есть combobox, itemssource которого заполняется из БД

```
UFSSPEntities context = new UFSSPEntities();
var RepliesVS = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("RepliesVS");
context.Replies.Load();
RepliesVS.Source = context.Replies.Local;
```

Следующим образом он привязывается:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource RepliesVS}}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=REPLY}"
```

Если поле REPLY равно null, то в combobox выбирается первое значение. Как можно сделать, чтобы выбирался пустой элемент вместо этого?

Comment: А что такое «пустой элемент»? Он есть в вашей коллекции?

Comment: Нет, его нет. Я не смогу добавить в базу элемент, первичный ключ которого будет NULL

Comment: Но в коллекцию-то вы его сможете добавить? Пустой элемент должен откуда-то взяться.